# Is it valid to call Array.map on an iterable that is not an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, array.prototype.map

This article: [Traversing the DOM with filter(), map(), and arrow functions](https://medium.com/@chuckdries/traversing-the-dom-with-filter-map-and-arrow-functions-1417d326d2bc) advocates such a use of `Array.map` that seems odd to me. More specifically, the author of the article claims the following piece of code is valid and actually better than the alternative `Array.from(elements).map(...)`:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("bgflag");
BgFlags = Array.prototype.map.call(elements,
        element =>
        ({
            height: element.offsetTop,
            bgsrc: element.dataset.bgsrc,
            bgcolor: element.dataset.bgcolor,
            size: element.dataset.size,
            name: element.id,
            image: parseInt(element.dataset.image)
        })
    );
```

This seems most suspicious to my untrained eye. We are calling `Array.prototype.map` on something that is not an `Array`. Unless it is somewhere explicitely stated that this is allowed, this smells like undefined behavior to me. I quickly scanned through [the relevant MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), but couldn't find that such a usage is allowed there.

And yet, the author of the article underlines:

> Even though map() is a function of Array.prototype, it works on any array-like iterable.

Is such a use valid, as he claims? If so, is this also the case with other `Array.prototype.*` functions, like `filter`, `slice`, maybe even `pop`, `push`, others?

Comment: Yes it is valid and an extremely common practice.

Comment: From the ES 5.1 spec: *The map function is intentionally generic; it does not require that its this value be an Array object. Therefore it can be transferred to other kinds of objects for use as a method. Whether the map function can be applied successfully to a host object is implementation-dependent.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Unless it is somewhere explicitely stated that this is allowed

It is, it's in [the specification](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.map):

> The `map` function is intentionally generic; it does not require that its this value be an `Array` object. Therefore it can be transferred to other kinds of objects for use as a method.

Most of the methods on `Array.prototype` have that note. The ones that can't be used that way don't have that note.

Whether you want to use it, therefore, is purely a matter of style. Different people will come down different ways on whether it's good/bad/indifferent style.

---

Side Note: If you're going to use `map` that way, rather than write that longhand each time, give yourself a shortcut:

```
const map = Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.map);
```

and then use it like this:

```
const result = map(arrayLike, e => /*...*/);
```

Live Example:

```js
const map = Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.map);

const arrayLike = {
  0: "zero",
  1: "one",
  2: "two",
  length: 3
};
const result = map(arrayLike, e => e.toUpperCase());
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes that generally works. However I agree to you that:

```
Array.from(elements).map(element => /*..*/);
// Or even
Array.from(elements, element => /*...*/);
```

is much cleaner.